# X11 applications over SSH receive bugged keyboard input

Tags: ssh, x11, keyboard

After ssh -X user@host and launching an application (for example zenmap), keyboard input into the X11 window is broken. Typing 192... appears and functions as erp...  Keys show up fine when typing into a normal CLI SSH session, only in a remote X11 application does the issue arise.  Any ideas as to how to solve this? It was working before I rebooted...

Comment: First, prefer `ssh -Y` to `ssh -X`, X11 is unfriendly to permissions sometimes.  Second, you will need to present a verifiable example: what Xorg are you running, on what system, connecting to what system and what are the outputs of the applications (e.g. ssh -v for a start).

Comment: unfamiliar with SSH -y; will look into that. Thanks for the information should further diagnoses be required to stabilize the system

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting the Xquartz Client-side resolved the issue.  My bad for not following rule 1. of turn it off and on again